# Redirect all subdomains to another host keeping the same subdomain

Tags: apache, http, apache2, virtualhost

I have a scenario where I need to redirect all subdomains (like *.mydomain.com) to be redirected to another host but keeping the same subdomain (like *.myanotherdomain.com). This is all on apache2.

So i tried below which obvious won't work for subdomains:
Like how do I redirect to another host keeping the exact subdomain prefix

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ServerName www.mydomain.com
     ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
     Redirect 301 / https://www.myanotherdomain.com

</VirtualHost>
```